# Gstreamer How to Capture Video from Specific Camera on Windows (MultipleCameras)

Tags: windows, video, camera, stream, gstreamer

My problem is I have to capture video from camera but I have multiple cameras. First one is default laptop camera and second is USB-attached Camera.

The problem is there is no 'device' attribute in gstreamer sources on Windows.

In Linux, I have found  " gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 \ "

In Windows instead of v412src, autovidesrc and videotestsrc are using. However, they don't have 'device' attribute.

As I searched in web, people are using dsvideoshowsrc but I did not get how they install it or how they implemented it. Some of them used ksvideosrc.

If anyone can help how can I resolve this issue, that would be very appreciated. I know many people had this problem and will have this problem. Therefore, clean explanation would benefit us so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `dshowvideosrc` is somewhat legacy, maybe helpful for some directshow only devices - I'm not even sure if that was ported to 1.0..

`ksvideosrc` should be good for your webcams. For reference here is the code:
https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/blob/master/sys/winks/gstksvideosrc.c

There you will see there are at least 3 different ways to select your device:

```
PROP_DEVICE_PATH
PROP_DEVICE_NAME
PROP_DEVICE_INDEX
```

So you can select your device via name or path - these may be GUIDs or something - I'm not sure (try to check within the code ;-)). But you also have an index which is probably the quickest way to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for answer that guided me. For people who uses same problem as me, just write " gst-launch-1.0 ksvideosrc device-index=1 ! autovideosink ". I thought ksvideosrc could not be installed during setup in my gstreamer library.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

gst-launch-1.0.exe -v ksvideosrc do-stats=TRUE ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

Comment: The question was for selecting SPECIFIC camera device with gstreamer and I described it on comment as ' gst-launch-1.0 ksvideosrc device-index=1 ! autovideosink '. That device-index attribute is for selecting specific device on your pc.

Answer (score 0):

`ksvideosrc` is good. Need to have `GStreamer` version 1.3 or above. Install or change to use all capture features. Typical install on windows does not come with `ksvideosrc`. 
For `ksvideosrc` device-index starts from 0. If Webcam is the only video capture device, it would be device-index 0.